# Distinction between correlation coefficient and coefficient of determination

Tags: statistics, correlation

In my stats class, I am learning about correlation coefficient and coefficient of determination.

I dont understand what the difference is between them. there are $r,\,$ $r^2$ and $R^2$.

$r^2$ and $R^2$ are both coefficient of determination but what is the difference?

Also, when do you use them? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Correlation.** In bivariate data $(x, y),$ the sample correlation $r$ estimates the population correlation $\rho$. The sample correlation measures the linear component of association. Positive values of $r$ indicate the extent to which $y$ increases linearly as $x$ increases. If all $x$'s are $0$ or all $y$'s are $0,$ the sample correlation $r$ is undefined, otherwise $-1 \le r \le 1.$

Consider the following data in R statistical software. (R is the name of the software, and has nothing to do with correlation.)
Each of the variables $y_1, y_2,$ and $y_3$ is defined as a function
of $x$, but only $y_1$ has a perfect linear association with $x,$
and so it is the only variable for which there is correlation $r = 1$
with $x$.

```
 x = 0:10;  y1 = x + 3;  y2 = x^2;  y3 = (x - 5)^2 
 cbind(x, y1, y2, y3)
 ##       x y1  y2 y3
 ##       0  3   0 25
 ##       1  4   1 16
 ##       2  5   4  9
 ##       3  6   9  4
 ##       4  7  16  1
 ##       5  8  25  0
 ##       6  9  36  1
 ##       7 10  49  4
 ##       8 11  64  9
 ##       9 12  81 16
 ##      10 13 100 25
 cor(x,y1)
 ## 1          # perfect linear association
 cor(x,y2)
 ## 0.9631427  # functional association, 'nearly' linear
 cor(x,y3)
 ## 0          # functional association, no linear component
```

As computed above, the correlations in the three plots below
(left to right) are: $r = 1, .96$ and $0.$

[image]

If we define $y4 = -3x + 2$,there is a perfect negative
linear association. If plotted, the line will have a negative
slope, and the correlation between $x$ and $y_4$ is $r = -1$.

If you want more illustrations of correlations for various
degrees of linear association and of nonlinear association,
see the start of the Wikipedia article on 'correlation and dependence'.

**Coefficient of determination.** As the notation indicates, the coefficient of
determination $r^2$ is the square of the correlation. Thus, by algebra,
$0 \leq r^2 \le 1.$

The coefficient of determination is often used in regression.
Roughly speaking, it expresses the degree to which the variation
in $y$ is 'explained' by the regression line of $y$ on $x$.
Some software uses capital $R^2$ for the coefficient of 
determination. (Perhaps this is a hold-over from early computer
days when computer terminals used only capital letters.)
In Minitab you will see the label `R-Sq` which is just
a way to print $r^2.$

Below is part of a printout of a [simple linear regression problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688770/) I 
did earlier today. In this case the regression line is
$\hat Y = 11.03 + 24.863x$, the correlation is $r = 0.954$ and
the coefficient of determination is
$r^2 =  0.910116.$ You can see how $r^2$ is shown as `R-Sq` at the end of
the printout (rounded and as a percentage).

```
 MTB > print 'x'

 x
    4   2   5   7   1   3   4   5   2   6

 MTB > print 'y'

 y
   90    60   170   190    40    80   100   130    70   150

 MTB > regr 'y' 1 'x'

 Regression Analysis: y versus x 

 The regression equation is
 y = 11.0 + 24.9 x

 Predictor    Coef  SE Coef     T      P
 Constant    11.03    11.92  0.93  0.382
 x          24.863    2.772  8.97  0.000

 S = 15.8977   R-Sq = 91.0%
```